# How to display root element in JFace TreeViewer?

Tags: java, treeview, swt, jface

I have a JFace Treeviewer, however it does not display the 'root' element that is passed as input. Only the children of the root are shown. 
Is it possible to display the root too?

Comment: show your code related to tree viewer.

Comment: dont see why that is needed. there is nothing special about the code

Answer (score 3):

The input is not decided as the root of the TreeViewer. Infact the treeviewer doesn't know which one is root and which one is not. Its decided by the [contentprovider.getElements()](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ITreeContentProvider.html#getElements%28java.lang.Object%29) methods. With most probability, I guess you are calling the getChildren() inside that method. That leads to returning the children of the root elements rather than returning the root elements themselves.

Comment: getElements() returns an object array. If i return new Object[]{element}, the tree shows inifinitely expanding root elems. what is the correct value to return from getElements() in this case?

Comment: The javadoc of getElements() specifically says that you should not return the inputElement. Are you setting the rootelement as the input? You should either create an empty/invisible root (if your model permits) or pass something other than the root element as the initial input. In the second case, the ContentProvider should be able to determine root from the initial input

Answer (score 1):

The TreeViewer's input element should not be displayed. The problem can be solved like this:

```
treeViewer.setInput("root");
```

And in the ContentProvider:

```
public Object[] getElements(Object arg0) {
    return new Object[] { rootItem }; // your root item you want to display
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into exactly the same problem and solved it by using a boolean field `treeInputSet` as follows in which `Model` is the domain class you want to display in the tree:

```
// Field to hold whether tree input was set
private boolean treeInputSet = false;    

// Other code...    

@Override 
public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement)
{
    if (inputElement instanceof Model)
    {
        if (treeInputSet)
        {
            Model model = (Model) inputElement;
            return model.getChildren().values().toArray();
        }
        else
        {
            treeInputSet = true;
            return new Object[] { inputElement };
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: -1: This is wrong. You cannot return a different result based on previous calls. This makes absolute no sense.